# $C$ such that $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}^n} k_i^2k_j^2|a_{ij}|^2 \leq C \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}^n} \|k\|^4|a_{ij}|^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

More generally, can we find $C_n>0$ such that

$$\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}^n} k_i^2k_j^2|a_{ij}|^2 \leq C \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}^n} \|k\|^2|a_{ij}|^4$$

for all $\{a_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{Z}^n} \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z}^n)$ where the above sums converge?

**My ideas so far:** $ij \leq i^2 + j^2$ shows that $C=1$ works. Is 1 the sharpest possible bound?

(This comes from showing that for $u,f$ periodic and smooth in $Q=[0,1]^n$ such that $\Delta u=f$, we have that $$\int_Q \left| \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \right|^2 \leq C \int_Q |f|^2,$$ and since we have been considering Fourier series of the form $$\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}^n}\hat{u}(k)e^{2\pi i \langle x,k \rangle}$$ in the problem, my strategy was to use that the $\ell^2$ norm is the same as the $L^2$ norm.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your mistake.  When you write out the right hand integral for the case $n=2$, you should get
$$ \sum_{i,j} (i^2+j^2)^2 |a_{ij}|^2 .$$
In other words, you knew what you were doing.  You just made an easy to make mistake.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. So it seems we can take $C \leq 1$ in fact. And it seems $C=1$ is sharp for $n=2$, by taking $i=j$ on the left hand side (I should have chosen different indices for the RHS). For $n>2$, it seems $C=1$ should be sharp as well, since we could consider the function $x_k^2$ and let $i=j=k$ on the LHS. Do you agree?

Comment: Oh, but the periodicity condition doesn't allow $x_k^2$...that might trip us up

Comment: To see that it is sharp, try something like $\exp(2 i \pi x_k)$.

Comment: Incidentally, the result is also true if you replace the $L_2$ norm with the $L_p$ norm for any $1<p<\infty$.  The constant depends upon $p$, and blows up as $p \to 1$ or $p \to \infty$.  This is definitely non-trivial.  Although it might be possible to do the case $p=4$ by multiplying everything out.

Answer (score 1):

Considering $a_{i,j}:=b_ic_j$, the existence of $C$ would imply those of a $C$ such that for each $(c_j)$ for which $\sum j^2c_j^2$ is finite, we have 
$$\sum_{j\geqslant 1}j^2c_j^2\leqslant C\sum_{j\geqslant 1}c_j^2,$$
which is not possible (take $c_N=1$ for a fixed $N$ and $c_j=0$ if $j\neq N$).